# How to disable Outlook forms designer

Tags: microsoft-outlook, outlook-form

My company has some important outlook forms that should not be messed with. Therefore I am seeking a way to prevent users from customizing the forms. Is this possible and how?

Answer (score 0):

There is a registry key that forbids starting the forms designer:

```
Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\<Version>\Outlook\NoOutlookFormsDesigner
```

When set to 1 it shows an error message (something like "your administrator disabled this") when trying to open the designer. You can add it to a group policy to spread the key.

Keep in mind that any user who knows about the registry key and has administrator permissions is able to bypass this. But AFAIK there is no other way.